Integration formula on basic affine space
Let $G$ be a connected reductive group, let $B$ be its Borel subgroup and $U$ the unipotent radical of $B$, the space $U\backslash G$ is called a basic affine space, the simplest example is the basic affine space $U\backslash G=U\backslash SL_{2}\cong \mathbb{A}^{2}-\{0\}$. There is a general theory of Fourier transform on basic affine space as developed by Braverman-Kazhdan https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9809112 and Gourvich-Kazhdan https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.07071 over $p$-adic local field.
In the $SL_{2}$ case, we can study the integration on $U\backslash G$ via the coordinates $(x,y)$ of $\mathbb{A}^{2}$, note that we can view the coordinate axes as divisors for $U\backslash G$. I am wondering do we have similar result for the basic affine space associated with the quasisplit unitary group $SU_{3}$? By this, I mean to find colors $D_{1},\cdots D_{n}$ of $U\backslash G=U\backslash SU_{3}$, and write any distribution $\Delta$ supported on a small neiborhood of $U1\hookrightarrow U\backslash G$
$$\Delta: \mathscr{S}(U\backslash G)\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$$
as $fdx_{1}dx_{2}\cdots dx_{n}$ where $x_{i}$ are the local coordinates such that $D_{i}=\{x_{i}=0\}$.
